# Progress slider for an audio player that's draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-audio-api

I am not sure what element would be best for the following purpose:

I made a audio player using Web Audio API in Javascript that shows the progress of the sound using the HTML5 progress tag. However, now I want to make it clickable, so that when I click it I get the value of where I can clicked and I adjust the sound file accordingly. I wanted to know which element to use. I am thinking jQuery slider UI.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I can't make it work. http://jsfiddle.net/7xQcb/

Comment: Is there any way you can share an image of how you want it to be?

[also you are using canvas for the wave, so make sure you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064913/display-tooltip-in-canvas-graph ]

Comment: Something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/nPKfj/
But I would like to do it the other way round, The div changes the range slider, because I don't like modifying the range slider

Answer (score 2):

**Q.** *Which element to use?*

**A.** Use jQuery UI slider

**Q.** *How to make it draggable?*

**A.** Use .draggable() from jQuery UI

**Q.** *How to get the value where I clicked?*

**A.** http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#method-value and check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032004/1912213

Comment: also check the **jQuery UI API** for the slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical